# Tags for document classes

Tags: discussion, tagging

I suggest we introduce tags clearly showing that a document class is concerned.

- [book-class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-class) would be clearer than just [book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) and would not interfere with questions regarding books - those made of paper.
- [letter-class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letter-class) could be distinguished from questions regarding letters as such.
- [slides-class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slides-class) shows that the class is meant and not the concept [slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slides) including beamer.

A first glance at the tag shows that a class is meant. We could omit a [documentclass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentclass) tag usually.

If I would get some positive comments and the question, let's say, 10 upvotes, I would create the [tag:*-class] tags plus some synonyms. For instance, beamer would be a good synonym for [beamer-class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beamer-class) but [slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slides) perhaps not for [slides-class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slides-class).

Comment: Looks good to me.  I think that tags should help someone decide whether or not they'll be able to have a go at answering a question so the more precise the tags are, the better they are for this purpose.

Comment: Also for refining a search using the [*-class] tag could be a good way, concept+class like [heading]+[book-class]. Just 100% clear: if I mean my *class*, I'll get that. Not some book review.

Comment: Would this mean `memoir-class` and `koma-script-class`? Because that could be confusing

Comment: @Seamus: `koma-script` is not a class. If at all, then `scrbook-class`. However, most non-standard classes have unambiguous names. Also, we now use plural tags, classes have singular names. I'm not satisfied with `book` for the book class and `letter` for the letter class, but for now I don't see an urgent need for action.