# Why are there {books} and {amsbook} tags but no {book} (class) tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I just asked [a question related to the book class on the main site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127466/how-can-i-insert-line-breaks-within-the-title-without-hardcoding-s-in-title). Upon choosing the tags for my question, I was surprised that there doesn't seem to be any tag associated with the `book` class.

A [books](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) tag exists, but it is not appropriate here:

> [books](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) is for questions which deal with books about TeX, LaTeX and other topics of this site. For questions regarding design and layout of books use [book-design](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-design) instead.

Besides, the `amsbook` class has its own tag. So why is there no [book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) or [book-class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-class) tag? I think it's a popular and quirky enough class for it to deserve its own tag.

I excavated a [2010 meta question by Stefan](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402/tags-for-document-classes), suggesting the creation of tags for document classes, which seemed to gather support. Why was no [book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) tag created?

Comment: Maybe you could give some specific examples of where the book class  is sufficiently different from other 'standard classes' (see lockstep's answer below) to warrant it's own tag?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although the [article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article) and [report](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/report) tags exist, it seems that whenever the [books](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) tag was incorrectly applied to a question about the `book` class, the tag was removed, but nobody bothered to create a separate [book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) tag. My guess is that such a tag (like [article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article) and [report](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/report)) would "only" reveal what should be revealed by a MWE, namely, the class used by the questioner. Any special expertise needed for questions about `book` is most likely also useful for `report`, and more often than not useful for `article`. The AMS classes sometimes deviate from the standard classes, but again there are similiarities between `amsart` and `amsbook` (there's no `amsreprt` class).

Another hint that those four tags were ill-conceived is that each of them has at most 2 followers -- compare that to the 35 followers of [memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memoir)  and the 31 of [koma-script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koma-script), both of them popular classes.

I suggest to *not* create a separate [book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) tag. Instead,

- either rename [report](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/report) to [report-book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/report-book);
- or better merge [article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article) and [report](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/report) into a new [standard-classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-classes) tag, and likewise merge [amsart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amsart) and [amsbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amsbook) into a new [ams-classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ams-classes) tag.

EDIT: Judging from the upvotes and comments, the consensus seems to be that the class-specific tags should be abandoned and generic tags [standard-classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-classes) and [ams-classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ams-classes) should be created. However, on second thought I share Jubob's concern that [standard-classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-classes) is likely to be overused, so I suggest to restrict the use of this tag to the "inner workings" of the standard classes (similar to the [latex-kernel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex-kernel) tag). The tag wiki excerpts could read as follows:

> {standard-classes} is about the inner workings of the standard classes
>   `article`, `book`, and `report`. Do not add this tag simply because
>   you use one of these classes; instead, choose the tags appropriate for
>   your specific problem.
>
> {ams-classes} is about the AMS classes `amsart`, `amsbook`, and
>   `amsproc`. When using this tag, add the tags appropriate for your
>   specific problem.

Following this definition, it is likely that some of the questions featuring [article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article) or [report](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/report) at the  moment should simply have these tags removed instead of replaced by [standard-classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-classes). I will check these questions in the next days.

Comment: I like the idea of a [tag:standard-classes] tag. However, it runs the risk of being overused, like the [tag:macros] tag can be. Would askers not be tempted to use [tag:standard-classes] whenever they post an MWE that uses one of those common classes?

Comment: I believe having generic tags like [tag:standard-classes] and [tag:ams-classes] makes the most sense.

Comment: @Jubobs Not (much) more than they are tempted to add the [tag:article] or [tag:report] tag. ;-)

Comment: there's already an `sv-classes` tag, so there's precedent for `standard-classes` and `ams-classes`.  but need to be careful about the existing `document-classes` tag (as opposed to `documentclass-writing`, which is nicely self-explanatory).

Comment: Should `letter` be included as a standard class too?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Good point. I suggest *not* to include it as it is fairly different from the other standard classes. Let's use the existing [tag:letters] tag.